# JavaScript onbeforedeactivate

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, internet-explorer-8

Internet Explorer 8

```
<input id="txt" type"text" />
<input id="but" type="button" value="button1" />

document.getElementById("txt").attachEvent("onbeforedeactivate", function (ev) {
  ev.returnEvent = false;
  return false;
});

document.getElementById("but").attachEvent("onclick", function (ev) {
  alert(99);
});
```

Starting with focus on input (type=text).
When I click the button, I expect only `onbeforedeactivate` event fires, instead `onclick` event fires too.
Is there a solution?

Comment: Focus stays on text input (and this is ok) and button onclick event doesn't fire

Answer (score 0):

When attaching event listener with `attachEvent`, the Event object can be found in `window.event` property, not in the first argument of callback function.

Comment: however button onclick event fire and I wont to avoid this.

Comment: @Massimo Why don't you just use `window.event.cancelBubble = true; window.event.returnValue = false` in `onclick` event handler? The event will fire, however it won't do anything.

Comment: The ratio of the code is the following: if the value typed in the text is valid, the button may riceive the focus (and onclick event fires), if the value typed is invalid, the focus has to remain in the text and no other event has to fire. I tried window.event.cancelBubble = true; window.event.returnValue = false; in onclick event handler, but the result is the same.